# Envió de datos de un Fragment a otro mediante bundle devuelve null

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Lo que quiero hacer es teniendo dos Fragments en el mismo Activity quiero pasar una fecha seleccionada en formato String desde el Fragment A hacia el Fragment B para poder trabajar allí con esa fecha.

**Fragment A:**

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarView, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                int mesActual = i1 + 1;
                String diaFormateado = (i2 < 10) ? "0" + String.valueOf(i2) : String.valueOf(i2);
                String mesFormateado = (mesActual < 10) ? "0" + String.valueOf(mesActual) : String.valueOf(mesActual);

                String fechaEscogida = i + "/" + mesFormateado + "/" + diaFormateado;

                interfaceComunicaFragments.enviarFecha(fechaEscogida);
            }
        });
```

Lo que aquí hago es que, cada vez que se selecciona un nuevo día del calendario, convierto a formato String la fechaEscogida y lo mando a un interface.

**Fragment A xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.CalendarioFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutCalendario"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <CalendarView
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/contenedorFragments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" /> 

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

En el Framelayout es donde cargo el Fragment B.

**SectionPagerAdapter**

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (position == 0) {
            fragment = rootFragment;
        } else {
            fragment = calendarioFragment;
        }
        return fragment;
    }
```

La aplicación consiste en un viewpager de 2 fragments y los cargo de esta manera (El segundo es el calendarioFragment que es el Fragment A).

**Interface:**

```
public interface IComunicaFragments {

    public void enviarCerdas(Cerda cerda);

    public void enviarFecha(String fecha);
}
```

Actúa de enlace entre el fragment y el Activity.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements IComunicaFragments {


    ListaPrincipalFragment listFragment;
    DetalleFragment detalleFragment;
    DiarioFragment diarioFragment;
    //MensualFragment mensualFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listFragment = new ListaPrincipalFragment();
        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    @Override
    public void enviarCerdas(Cerda cerda) {
        detalleFragment = new DetalleFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("objeto",cerda);
        detalleFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                replace(R.id.root_frame, detalleFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void enviarFecha(String fecha) {
        diarioFragment = new DiarioFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("fecha", fecha);
        diarioFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    }
}
```

Recoge la fecha la carga en el Bundle y la envía al fragment B "diarioFragment".

**Fragment B:**

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            String fecha = bundle.getString("fecha");
            System.out.println("LLEGA " + fecha);
        }
    }
```

Finalmente, en el fragment que deseo recoger la fecha compruebo lo que llega pero no me saca nada, y si elimino la comprobación del bundle me lo saca null.

La idea que tengo es la que comento, cada vez que se seleccione un día distinto en el calendarView del Fragment A, recibir esa fecha en el Fragment B. Si no es optimo hacerlo de este modo estoy dispuesto a cambiarlo.

Comment: ¿Tienes ambos fragments en pantalla o en que momento cambias al fragment B?, creo que el problema podría estar ahí

Comment: Los tengo ambos en pantalla, en el layout del fragment A hay un framelayout que contiene el fragment B. Por eso he obviado la parte de la transicion con el replace y demas.

Comment: ¿agregas ambos fragments desde el xml o en el onCreate del Main Activity?, por favor agrega el código de tu layout y el código de tu activity donde recuperas ambos fragments

Comment: Que tal, creo que tu problema es aca, diarioFragment = new DiarioFragment(); ya que estas creando una nueva referencia de diarioFragment en vez de usar la que ya tenias.
O puede que no, pero todo depende, si nos compartes el codigo de como estas mostrando el fragment.

Comment: He incluido el xml del Fragment A, el mainActivity completo y la parte del PageView donde asigno los dos fragments a dos tabs. Espero que esto ayude.

Comment: ¿El fragment B lo colocas dentro de CalendarioFragment?, en ese caso no es necesario usar una interface en tu mainActivity, puedes llamar directamente a un metodo del fragment B desde el fragment Calendario

Comment: Lo que queria hacer es cargar en el FrameLayout de CalendarioFragment el fragment B (pulsando un switch que cargaria en su lugar otro fragment, pero la linea donde lo cargo es: getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedorFragments, diarioFragment).commit();                                                                                    contendorFragments es el FrameLayout y diarioFragment es mi Fragment B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu fragment B(diario) está dentro del fragment A(calendario), no necesitas pasar por la Main Activity para enviarle datos, puedes crear un método públco en el fragment B para actualizar la fecha. Tu código debería ser similar a esto:

Fragment A

```
public class CalendarioFragment extends Fragment {

    private DiarioFragment diarioFragment;

    public CalendarioFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        diarioFragment=new DiarioFragment();

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendario, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedorFragments, diarioFragment).commit();
        CalendarView calendarView=view.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarView, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                int mesActual = i1 + 1;
                String diaFormateado = (i2 < 10) ? "0" + String.valueOf(i2) : String.valueOf(i2);
                String mesFormateado = (mesActual < 10) ? "0" + String.valueOf(mesActual) : String.valueOf(mesActual);

                String fechaEscogida = i + "/" + mesFormateado + "/" + diaFormateado;

                diarioFragment.actualizaFecha(fechaEscogida);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Fragment B

```
public class DiarioFragment extends Fragment {



    public DiarioFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_diario, container, false);
    }

    public void actualizaFecha(String fecha){
        //Haz algo con la fecha
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(),fecha,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Revisando tu codigo no deberias tener problema en recibir el valor, me parece que el problema en realidad es al llamar el metodo `enviarFecha()` aqui  el valor de fecha seguramente es null

```
   @Override
    public void enviarFecha(String fecha) {
        diarioFragment = new DiarioFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("fecha", fecha);
        diarioFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    }
```

**Unicamente el valor de la fecha sera diferente a null si previamente seleccionas una fecha en el calendario de otra forma esta seria la razon de obtener un valor null.**

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarView, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                ...
                ...
                ...
                interfaceComunicaFragments.enviarFecha(fechaEscogida);
            }
        });
```